# How to insert an element into an array that is already preoccupied?

Tags: c

I've been struggling to figure out how to build an array such that every cell has the PID of a child process in the order they were created.. The sample output:

```
    PID: 19581, Parent PID: 19579
    Data[0]: 19581
    Data[1]: 1
    Data[2]: 2
    Data[3]: 3
    Data[4]: 4
    Data[5]: 5
    Data[6]: 6
    Data[7]: 7
    Data[8]: 8
    Data[9]: 9
    PID: 19582, Parent PID: 19579
    Data[0]: 0
    Data[1]: 19582
    Data[2]: 2
    Data[3]: 3
    Data[4]: 4
    Data[5]: 5
    Data[6]: 6
    Data[7]: 7
    Data[8]: 8
    Data[9]: 9
    PID: 19583, Parent PID: 19579
    Data[0]: 0
    Data[1]: 1
    Data[2]: 19583
    Data[3]: 3
    Data[4]: 4
    Data[5]: 5
    Data[6]: 6
    Data[7]: 7
    Data[8]: 8
    Data[9]: 9
    PID: 19584, Parent PID: 19579
    Data[0]: 0
    Data[1]: 1
    Data[2]: 2
    Data[3]: 19584
    Data[4]: 4
    Data[5]: 5
    Data[6]: 6
    Data[7]: 7
    Data[8]: 8
    Data[9]: 9
    PID: 19579, Parent PID: 10296
    Data[0]: 0
    Data[1]: 1
    Data[2]: 2
    Data[3]: 3
    Data[4]: 4
    Data[5]: 5
    Data[6]: 6
    Data[7]: 7
    Data[8]: 8
    Data[9]: 9
```

and so forth. This is probably the hardest part of the code for me. The farthest I can reach is what I have below. Any guidance on what to do next will be very helpful.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
         pid_t childpid;
         pid_t mypid;
         int numberOfProcess, i;

         mypid = getpid();

         if(argc != 2){
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
         }

         //Determine the number of child process.
         numberOfProcess = atoi(argv[1]);//Look up atoi(int)
         int data[numberOfProcess];      //Data array

         for(i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++){
              childpid = fork();
              if (childpid <= 0)
                    break;
         }
         if (childpid != 0){
            for (i=1; i < numberOfProcess; i++)
            wait(NULL);
         }

         fprintf(stderr,"\nPID: %ld, Parent PID: %ld\n", (long)getpid(),(long)getppid());
         for (i=0; i < numberOfProcess; i++){
            int j;
            data[j]= j;
            printf ("Data[%i]: %i\n",i,data[j++]);
         }
         return 0;
```

}

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: The example I provided above is how the output should look like. Im having issues with how to put the PID into its corresponding memory. First PID into Data[0], Second PID into Data[1], Third PID into Data[2], Fourth PID into Data[3], and so forth. What steps should I take to make that happen?

Comment: @TamerTas Your code compiles really oddly. I dont think your code is correct.

Comment: Do not deface your question after others have taken the time to answer you. I've rolled this last edit back.

Answer (score -1):

When the parent process `fork()`s, the child process gets an exact copy of its parent's array of pids.

What you need in your parent process's loop is that after it `fork()`s, only the child process should set its proper array slot with its pid, while the parent process just waits for its child to exit before it continues with the loop.

The code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int number_of_processes, i;
    int data[number_of_processes];

    number_of_processes = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_processes; ++i)
        data[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_processes; ++i) {
        childpid = fork();
        /* fork() failure */
        if (childpid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* Child's code */
        if (childpid == 0) {
            data[i] = (int) getpid();
            fprintf(stderr, "\nmy pid = %d\tmy parent's pid = %d\n", 
                    (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
            for (i = 0; i < number_of_processes; ++i)
                fprintf(stderr, "\n\tdata[%d] == %d", i, data[i]);
            fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* Parent's code */
        else
            wait(NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\nmy pid = %d\tmy parent's pid = %d\n", 
                    (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_processes; ++i)
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\tdata[%d] == %d", i, data[i]);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints but there are other random values in each cells. There were some instances whereas the PID did not move to the next cell.

Comment: @user2093028: Provide an example output please? It works exactly as in your example on my gcc 4.8.1. Are you sure you didn't change the code? Maybe you forgot to initialize the array before the loop hence the random values?

Comment: @user2093028: ok, so what my answer misses is the table to be printed for the parent process too? Rest are exactly as you posted.

Comment: @user2093028: Isn't that what you were looking for? Feed me back so I can help.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Your question isn't clear. But, I believe you are trying to build an array such that every cell has the `pid` of a child process in the order they were created.</strike>

The problem in your code is `Linux` uses **Copy on Write** for forked processes which means the array will be copied into the child's address space and **then** the value will be replaced. Leaving you with **n copied arrays** for **n children** with each having **only** one cell altered. You shouldn't write `pid` to array using children. Parent process should handle that.

**Edit:** Updated the code now that I understand your question.

Take a look at the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int i, numberOfProcess;
     pid_t mypid, childpid;

     mypid = getpid();

     if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
     }

     //Determine the number of child process.
     numberOfProcess = atoi(argv[1]);//Look up atoi(int)
     int data[numberOfProcess];      //Data array

     // Initial values for the array before being copied
     // to the child address space.
     for(i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++){ data[i] = i; }

     for(i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++){
          childpid = fork();

          // If child, learn the process ID and assign it. Then break the loop.
          if (childpid <= 0) { data[i] = getpid(); break; }
     }

     if (childpid != 0){
         for (i=1; i < numberOfProcess; i++) { wait(NULL); }
     }
     else {
         fprintf(stderr,"\nPID: %ld, Parent PID: %ld\n", (long)getpid(),(long)getppid());

         for (i=0; i < numberOfProcess; i++){ printf ("Data[%i]: %i\n",i,data[j++]); }
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This isn't even compilable.

Comment: `I believe you are trying to build an array such that every cell has the pid of a child process in the order they were created.` OP's example output doesn't ask for that.

Comment: @user2093028 So you want to build n arrays for n childs with one cell altered right? I thought that was the problem.

Comment: @TamerTas: According to his example output however, he shows he needs an array for each child.

Comment: @TamerTas, you got the correct output!I see what you did with the data[i] at the top. Thank you very much!